# Where to get the release version of lollipop for Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, 5.0-lollipop

I'm looking for the Lollipop OS that I can sideload to my Nexus 7 2012 and supposedly they released Lollipop for Nexus 7 2012 today (Nov 3, 2014).  Is there a site I can go to download the OTA file?

The official version is not [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) yet.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm not asking for when the device will update on its own - but where I can get the new image.

Comment: It will come out on the site when Google release it. There is no official release date. The Nexus 6 and 9 will be released with it today, but the other Nexus devices don't have any release date. Even if it was out today, it's early morning in the US still so they're not even in the office

Comment: I read in various sources that the new image would come out today.  Though, the sources weren't Google.

Comment: Yeah that was one article that got copied all over the place. Google haven't given any indication at all. Maybe it will be today, maybe not. The N6 and N9 images should be soon, the other devices 'when it's ready.'

Answer (score 2):

The place you've already linked is where the downloads will show up first. Normally OTA updates are staged-rollout, meaning you'll have to wait until your device/region is eligible to receive the update unfortunately.

Comment: Yep, "when it's out" is the only answer at the moment. A few guesses were today (November 3rd) but not from any official channels. The Nexus 6 and 9 are released today with Lollipop, so maybe that's what's causing the confusion.